# How do you know when you are using a multi gpu?

Tags: keras, gpu

I have 2 gpus on my local machines, but i'm not sure that the model I am training is using both of them (the speed has not changed much).

My code:

```
def get_model():
    base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3), include_top=False)
    #base_model.trainable = False

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(base_model)
    model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(196, activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()

    model = multi_gpu_model(model,gpus=2)

    #optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])

    return model
```

I just added the `multi_gpu_model` setting, but am not sure that this is enough. I checked nvidia-smi every 0.5 seconds, but seems like only one gpu is working. How do I make sure that it uses the full 2 gpus?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux and Nvidia GPUs, you can do the following in a terminal

```
nvidia-smi
```

Which will show you some stats about the GPUs available on your system.

You can run it automatically every 2 seconds like this to see how power/memory usage changes during training:

```
watch -n 2 nvidia-smi
```

If you see nothing or the `nvidia-smi` command fails, you likely don't have the correct drivers installed.

If theya re showing, but Keras/Tensorflow is not finding them, have [a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow) for more checks for Tensorflow backend.

Comment: yes I'm using 2 GPU's but I want to know I'm using 2 GPU parallelly when I'm training the neural network

Comment: Watching the stats shown in the output of `nvidia-smi` will show you that. If both are being heavily utilised at the same time, they are being used in parallel.